# Reac-Router v4, server side rendering, ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, server-rendering

I'm using react-router version 4 and trying to handle routes on the server.

All tutorials including [offical Server Rendering guide on ReactTraining repo](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ServerRendering.md) and [React Router tutorial - server side rendering](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/13-server-rendering) are using React Router v3.

The only available guide out there is [Server side rendering with React Router version 4](https://react-router.now.sh/ServerRouter).

I have followed same steps, but i got the following error :

```
 _reactDom2.default.render(_react2.default.createElement(App, null), document.getElementById('app'));
                                                                            ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/fakhruddinabdi/Projects/fotomantic/fotomantic.com/public/server.bundle.js:271:70)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/fakhruddinabdi/Projects/fotomantic/fotomantic.com/public/server.bundle.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/fakhruddinabdi/Projects/fotomantic/fotomantic.com/public/server.bundle.js:59:13)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/fakhruddinabdi/Projects/fotomantic/fotomantic.com/public/server.bundle.js:20:30)
    at /Users/fakhruddinabdi/Projects/fotomantic/fotomantic.com/public/server.bundle.js:40:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/fakhruddinabdi/Projects/fotomantic/fotomantic.com/public/server.bundle.js:43:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
```

Here is my web

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {

  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'server.js'),

  output: {
    filename: 'public/server.bundle.js',
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('public/styles.css'),
  ],

  target: 'node',

  // keep node_module paths out of the bundle
  externals: fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')).concat([
    'react-dom/server', 'react/addons',
  ]).reduce(function (ext, mod) {
    ext[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod
    return ext
  }, {}),

  node: {
    __filename: true,
    __dirname: true
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      }, {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&name=/[hash].[ext]',
      }, {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css', 'sass']),
      },
    ],
  },

}
```

And my server.js :

```
import { createServer } from 'http';
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { ServerRouter, createServerRenderContext } from 'react-router';
import App from './src/components/App';

createServer((req, res) => {

  // first create a context for <ServerRouter>, it's where we keep the
  // results of rendering for the second pass if necessary
  const context = createServerRenderContext()

  // render the first time
  let markup = renderToString(
    <ServerRouter
      location={req.url}
      context={context}
    >
      <App/>
    </ServerRouter>
  )

  // get the result
  const result = context.getResult()

  // the result will tell you if it redirected, if so, we ignore
  // the markup and send a proper redirect.
  if (result.redirect) {
    res.writeHead(301, {
      Location: result.redirect.pathname
    })
    res.end()
  } else {

    // the result will tell you if there were any misses, if so
    // we can send a 404 and then do a second render pass with
    // the context to clue the <Miss> components into rendering
    // this time (on the client they know from componentDidMount)
    if (result.missed) {
      res.writeHead(404)
      markup = renderToString(
        <ServerRouter
          location={req.url}
          context={context}
        >
          <App />
        </ServerRouter>
      )
    }
    res.write(markup)
    res.end()
  }
}).listen(8080)
```

Comment: Where does the line `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));` exist in your project? The only reason I could see for that line being run on the server is it it is in your `App.js` file, which it shouldn't be.

Comment: You right Paul .. it exist in App.js .. but i don't know where to put it instead

Comment: I just started to create a file namely client.js and set it as an entry point for webpack then put the line there ..
Do you its a right way ?

Comment: That sounds about right. `ReactDOM.render` is a client side function, so it should exist in a file that is only run on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out.!

As @Paul S mentioned in the comments the problem comes from putting this linke : `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));` inside the `App` component.

So i just created another file namely client.js and and moved the line there. So it works.

Its because `App` component is shared between server side and client side. So you need to take the client codes out of `App` component if you want to deal with server side rendering.

Thanks to Paul.

Comment: And then how do you exactly call this file and use it ?

Comment: You should add client.js in your webpack.config as entry point
Are you using webpack ?

Answer (score 0):

I've created starter based on redux server-side rendering and react-router v4 server-side rendering docs: https://github.com/gzoreslav/react-redux-saga-universal-application